# Issue with DB2 database connection with uname/password

Tags: ubuntu, db2

In Ubuntu terminal when i do:
$ db2 connect to sample user db2inst1 using db2inst1

I get the response:

The database server was unable to perform authentication because security related database manager files on the server do not have the required operating system permissions. SQLSTATE=08001

I thought there is user privilege issues so tried using 
db2iupdt to update instance to db2inst1 but got the error 
db2iupdt command not found.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install as root or as user?

Comment: I installed as non-root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between root and non-root installations of DB2, the [limitations are documented](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/c0050568.html). One limitation of non-root installation is that by default the DB2 instance cannot user the operating system for authentication.

You could use [db2rfe](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/c0050568.html) (root feature enablement) to get it enabled. You would need to edit the related configuration file, set `ENABLE_OS_AUTHENTICATION` to `YES` and then run `db2rfe` with the [configuration file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0050569.html). On Ubuntu this would be something like:

```
sudo db2rfe -f yourConfigFile
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a non-root install, this perfectly worked for me